# Set selenium speed doesn't work in robot framework

Tags: performance, selenium, robotframework, automation-testing

I just login into a website, i guess it was too fast so i put "set selenium speed" under "maximize browser window" but it does not work. what happen?
here's my code.

```
*** Settings ***
Library     SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
LoginTest
    open browser                    https://www.demoblaze.com/index.html                    Chrome
    set selenium speed                                                                      3seconds
    maximize browser window
    click element                   id:login2
    wait until element is visible   id:loginusername
    input text                      id:loginusername                                        etane.gapuro@gmail.com
```

Comment: Hiya, could you format your code in code block exactly as you have it in your code editor as we can't see whether the issue could be based on the syntax you're using - If I was to format this correctly it works as expected.

Comment: Instead of changing speeds properties it's much better to wait for the element you click (login2) to actually appear; just like you do with loginusername.

Answer (score 0):

Check indentation or a format issue for the keyword `set selenium speed`

Answer (score 0):

Add some value to `set selenium speed`
you can use something like this  **`set selenium speed  2`**  it will wait for two minutes